# Retrieve only part of String in Java

Tags: java

Let's say I have this String here:

```
"40.7486720036497\n-73.9856280013919\n20 W 34th St, New York, NY 10001, USA"
```

How do I only retrieve `W 34th St, New York, NY 10001, USA` in the shortest way?

I have written some code but I find it too long and overkill.

Comment: Can you explain your approach?

Comment: Split string by newline, and grab the 3rd element in the resulting array.

Comment: If all your strings are in that format, you could probably write a regex which extracts the coordinates and the address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As TravelingTechGuy's comment suggests:

```
String myString = "40.7486720036497\n-73.9856280013919\n20 W 34th St, New York, NY 10001, USA";
String theAddress = myString.split("\n")[2]
```